# How to split a multiple delimiter string to an array converting only the numbers to integers in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, split

I have a sting like the one below and I want to convert it to an array so that I can sort the list by the donation amount.
What'd be the most efficient way to do it in Ruby?

```
names = "
    Andres - Donation: $230 - Time: 568

    Sarah - Donation: $345 - Time: 600

    James - Donation: $134 - Time: 340
    "
```

I'm trying to get each line into an Array as below and sort by Donation amount.

```
>array = [["Andres - Donation: $230 - Time: 568"],
>["Sarah - Donation: $345 - Time: 600"],
>["James - Donation: $134 - Time: 340"]]
```

but I'm struggling to find a way to do it. I could do it only by modifying the order of the items in each array and use the sort method adjusted to sort in descending order.

```
array2 = [["Donation: $230 - Time: 568 - Andres"],
["Donation: $345 - Time: 600 - Sarah"],
["Donation: $134 - Time: 340 - James"]]

array2.sort! { |a,b| b <=> a }
```

For splitting the Array I've tried

```
names_Array = names.split(/\n/)
```

Comment: What array do you expect to get? Have you tried something to accomplish this?

Comment: BTW, `"""..."""` is equivalent to `"..."`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We'd like to see more evidence of your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you split your long string into an array of strings as you already did:

```
array = names.split(/\n/)
```

I leave it to you to clean out the empty lines.
You don't want to compare the whole strings, you want to compare the donation values. For that, use a function that extracts the value from a string, like

```
def donation(s)
    regex = /.*: \$(\d+) -.*$/
    m = s.match(regex)
    m ? m.captures.first.to_i : 0
end
```

Here, I use a regular expression to extract the decimal number between ": $" and " -". If there is no match, the function returns 0, otherwise the decimal amount.

Now, use the function to compare two strings:

```
array.sort {|a,b| donation(b) <=> donation(a)}
```

and you get your list sorted by donation amount (descending):

```
["    Sarah - Donation: $345 - Time: 600", "    Andres - Donation:    $230 - Time: 568", "    James - Donation: $134 - Time: 340", "", "",    "", "    "]
```

Again, its up to you to process it further.

Comment: To remove empty lines just change `split(/\n/)` to `split(/\n+/)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    (?<=\$)  # match a dollar sign in a positive lookbehind
    \d+      # match >= 1 digit
    (?=\s-)  # match a space followed by a dash in a positive lookahead
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode

names.strip.split(/\n+/).sort_by { |s| puts "s[r]=#{s[r]}"; s[r].to_i }
  #=> ["    James - Donation: $134 - Time: 340",
  #    "Andres - Donation: $230 - Time: 568",
  #    "    Sarah - Donation: $345 - Time: 600"]
```

If you want to remove the extra spaces:

```
names.strip.split(/\n+/).map(&:strip).sort_by { |s| s[r].to_i }
  #=> ["James - Donation: $134 - Time: 340",
  #    "Andres - Donation: $230 - Time: 568",
  #    "Sarah - Donation: $345 - Time: 600"]
```

If, as specified in the question, you want to put each string in a one-element array:

```
names.strip.split(/\n+/).map(&:strip).sort_by { |s| s[r].to_i }.map { |s| [s] }
  #=> [["James - Donation: $134 - Time: 340"],
  #    ["Andres - Donation: $230 - Time: 568"],
  #    ["Sarah - Donation: $345 - Time: 600"]]
```